# jQuery Check parent for class

Tags: jquery, dom, styles

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I want to change the CSS background-image of all 'li' elements that aren't direct children of a ul with the class of 'library_display'.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="library_display treeview">
    <li>General Competencies
        <ul>
            <li>Achievement Orientation
                <ul>
                    <li class="modal" id="itm_59_modal">
                        <a href="#">Argle Bargle</a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="myUrl" class="modal" id="itm_14_modal">Adaptability</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Leadership Competencies
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="myUrl" class="modal" id="itm_22_modal">Critical Judgment</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="myUrl" class="modal" id="itm_2_modal">Change Management</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**:
This is the code (in a document.ready statement) that is being executed:

```
if (!$('.treeview li').parents('ul:first').hasClass("library_display")){
    $('.treeview li').css({'background':'url(branch.png) 0px 0px no-repeat'});
}
```

It's not having any affect right now.  If I remove the if statement, it will have the affect I want on all list items, not just the ones I want.

Edit: Thanks for the code block. I was having some issues getting that working properly.

Comment: Can't you just pick all the first level li inside the libarary_display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only affect the `<li>` elements that are at nested at least two levels within `ul.library_display`

```
$(".library_display li li").css({
   'background':'url(branch.png) 0px 0px no-repeat'
});
```

jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: No problem. If you like this answer best you can click the checkmark to the left of it to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.library_display').children('li').find('li').css(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('.treeview li').parents('ul:first').hasClass("library_display")){
    $('.treeview li').css({'background':'url(branch.png) 0px 0px no-repeat'});
}
```

This statement is true for some, and false for others, which doesn't make it a valid `if` statement. You'd want to either iterate over all of the `li`s, or make a huge selector:

```
$('.treeview li').each(function()
{
  if ($(this).parents('ul:first').hasClass('library_display')
  {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(branch.png) 0px 0px no-repeat');
  }
});
```